Trufflehog still finding secrets in GitHub after modifying history
I ran trufflehog against my GitHub Org. I discovered some secrets.
I then followed the steps below to cleanup my history

Installed bfg repo cleaner and trufflehog

Performed git clone --bare git@github.com:MyOrg/MyRepo.git

Created a file named sensitive.txt with one line, containing a password that had been leaked into GitHub.

Executed bfg --replace-text sensitive.txt

Run git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive from within the bare repo's folder

Run git push --force --all


Now comes the interesting part.
The secret is still available in GitHub when I visit
https://github.com/MyOrg/MyRepo/blob/<commit-sha-where-the-sensitive-data-was-added>/folder1/folder2/filename.php#L13

This is more or less expected since github states that:

those commits may still be accessible elsewhere:

In any clones or forks of your repository

Directly via their SHA-1 hashes in cached views on GitHub

Through any pull requests that reference them



So running
trufflehog github --only-verified git@github.com:MyOrg/MyRepo.git

still finds that commit and the secret.
What I don't understand is why
trufflehog git --only-verified git@github.com:MyOrg/MyRepo.git

i.e. the git scanner still finds the secret, while at the same time trying to checkout the specific commit results in an error
git checkout <commit-sha-where-the-sensitive-data-was-added>
error: pathspec '<commit-sha-where-the-sensitive-data-was-added>' did not match any file(s) known to git

